# Sqlite のCallbackが実行される順番

Tags: monaca

MonacaでSqliteを利用しています。
複数のFunctionをネストしてSQLを実行していますが
Callbackが実行される順番がわかりません。
以下のようにネストして実行した場合
Main(); → sub(); → execSql(・・・, execCB);

想定
Main in
　sub in
　　execSql in
　　　execCB in
　　　execCB end
　　execSql end
　sub end
Main end

実際の実行結果
Main in
　sub in
　　execSql in
　　execSql end
　sub end
Main end
　　　execCB in
　　　execCB end
ネストしてスタックされている、関数が終わってから
Callbackは実行されるものなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それは非同期だからです。
いつコールバックされるかわからないので、`想定`のような考えでプログラムを組むと、実行した結果が正しく取得できないなどの現象に悩まされます。

Comment: 同居と非同期 忘れてました。
ありがとうございます。